# How to merge multipolygon into one smoothly

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, geojson, shapely

I have multipolygon consisting two polygons. How can I merge them with a simple script so they would make polygon instead of multipolygon? I need to connect them even if it would cover the unneeded area. Also need this to work with n polygons in multipolygon.

For better understanding I need a single polygon instead of multipolygon, because multipolygon is

```
[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y], [x,y],[x,y],[x,y], [x,y],[x,y],[x,y]]
```

but I need

```
[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]]
```

[Check this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2kY8.png)

I have tried to use python shapely for doing this, but no luck.

Comment: have a look at [ST_ConcaveHull](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ST_ConcaveHull`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html) is what you're looking for. This function calculates the concave geometry of a given geometry (its vertices) and returns a single geometry.

Consider the following MultiPolygon

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)), ((20 35, 45 20, 30 5, 10 10, 10 30, 20 35), (30 20, 20 25, 20 15, 30 20)))
```

[image]

The function `ST_ConcaveHull` expects a second parameter, which sets the concaveness of the computed hull:

> The **param_pctconvex** controls the concaveness of the computed hull. A value of 1 produces the convex hull. A value of 0 produces a hull of maximum concaveness (but still a single polygon). Values between 1 and 0 produce hulls of increasing concaveness. Choosing a suitable value depends on the nature of the input data, but often values between 0.3 and 0.1 produce reasonable results.

Check which value for `param_pctconvex` best fits your use case. Setting it to 0.1 gives you the following polygon:

```
WITH j (geom) AS  (
  VALUES ('SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)), 
                     ((20 35, 45 20, 30 5, 10 10, 10 30, 20 35), 
                     (30 20, 20 25, 20 15, 30 20)))'::geometry)
)
SELECT ST_ConcaveHull(geom,0.1) FROM j
```

[image]

Alternatively you can set a third (boolean) parameter to allow holes in the output:

> The polygon will not contain holes unless the optional `param_allow_holes` argument is specified as true